# I want one controller to affect the whole Rig

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

I have created a rig that moves all the desired parts but I need one main control to affect **everything** at once such that individual controls rotate around allowed axis when that main control is moved [image: Image showing rig]